# Codename One: 405 Method Not Allowed error

Tags: codenameone

I had been developing and testing on the Codename One **simulator and everything worked fine**.

However, when I tested it on a real Android device, I get a 405 Method Not Allowed error. This happened on both a POST and GET request.

I suspect it is the @Consume and @Produces which are causing the problem. How do I fix this?

Here are my server side code:

```
@GET
@Path("/all/{language}")
@Produces("application/json")
public final Response getAllCelebrities(@PathParam("language") String language) {
    String celebritiesJSONString = CelebrityActions.getAllCelebritiesNamesJSONString(language);
    return Response.ok(celebritiesJSONString).build();
}

@POST
@Path("/login")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces("text/plain")
public final Response login(
        @FormParam("loginid") String loginid,
        @FormParam("password") String password
) {
    System.out.println("login 0 started");
    Long fanID;
    try {
        fanID = AccountsActions.login(loginid, password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Response.serverError().entity(e.getMessage()).build();
    }
    if (fanID == null) {
        return responseFanIDNotFoundError();
    }
    System.out.println("This is printed out!!!");
    System.out.println("login 100 ended");
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

And here's my log upon execution of the login() method:

```
login 0 started
This is printed out!!!
login 100 ended
```

which means the server side method was ready to return a 200 response.

What is causing the Android client to show a 405 Method Not Allow error?

**EDIT**: I'm adding my cient-side code here:
*(note that this one handles a cookie from a server)*

```
public class Login extends PostConnection {

private final String LoginEndpoint = "account/login";

private String loginIDString;
private String loginPasswordString;

// Tested and works on simulator!
public Login(String loginIDString, String loginPasswordString) {
    super();
    endpoint = LoginEndpoint;
    this.loginIDString = loginIDString;
    this.loginPasswordString = loginPasswordString;
}

@Override
protected void prepareParametersMap() {
    parametersMap = new HashMap<>();
    parametersMap.put("loginid", loginIDString);
    parametersMap.put("password", loginPasswordString);
}

}

public abstract class PostConnection extends PostPutConnection {

public PostConnection() {
    super();
}

public boolean connect() throws IOException {
    connectionRequest.setHttpMethod("POST");
    return super.connect();
}
}

public abstract class PostPutConnection extends Connection {

protected HashMap<String, String> parametersMap;

public PostPutConnection() {
    super();
}

protected static final void setPostParameters(ConnectionRequest connectionRequest, HashMap<String, String> parametersMap) {
    Set<String> paramateterKeys = parametersMap.keySet();
    Iterator<String> parameterKeysIterator = paramateterKeys.iterator();
    while (parameterKeysIterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = parameterKeysIterator.next();
        String value = parametersMap.get(key);
        connectionRequest.addArgument(key, value);
    }
}

protected abstract void prepareParametersMap();

public boolean connect() throws IOException {
    prepareParametersMap();
    setPost();
    setPostParameters();
    return super.connect();
}

private void setPostParameters() {
    setPostParameters(connectionRequest, parametersMap);
}

private final void setPost() {
    connectionRequest.setPost(true);
}
}

public abstract class Connection {

private final static String protocol = "http";
private final static String domain = "192.168.0.109:20000";

protected ConnectionRequest connectionRequest;
protected String endpoint;

public Connection() {
    super();
    init();
}

protected void init() {
    connectionRequest = new ConnectionRequest();
    connectionRequest.setCookiesEnabled(true);
    ConnectionRequest.setUseNativeCookieStore(true);
}

public boolean connect() throws IOException {
    connectionRequest.setUrl(protocol + "://" + domain + "/" + endpoint);
    NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connectionRequest);
    int responseCode = getResponseCode();
    return responseCode == 200 ? true : false;
}

private int getResponseCode() {
    int responseCode = connectionRequest.getResponseCode();
    return responseCode;
}
}
```

And another method below:
*(note that this one does **not** handle cookies)*

```
public class GetAllCelebrities extends GetConnection {

private final String GetCelebritiesEndpoint = "celebrity/all";

public GetAllCelebrities(String language) {
    super();
    endpoint = GetCelebritiesEndpoint + "/" + language;
}

}

public abstract class GetConnection extends Connection {

    private Map<String, Object> responseData;

    public GetConnection() {
        super();
    }

    public boolean connect() throws IOException {
        connectionRequest.setHttpMethod("GET");
        boolean connectResult = super.connect();
        if (!connectResult) {
            return false;
        }
        responseData = getResponseResult();
        return true;
    }

    private Map<String, Object> getResponseResult() throws IOException {
        byte[] responseData = connectionRequest.getResponseData();
        ByteArrayInputStream responseDataBAIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(responseData);
        InputStreamReader responseDataISR = new InputStreamReader(responseDataBAIS, "UTF-8");
        JSONParser responseDateJSONParser = new JSONParser();
        Map<String, Object> responseResult = responseDateJSONParser.parseJSON(responseDataISR);
        return responseResult;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getResponseData() {
        return responseData;
    }
}
```

And it is called like:

```
private Map<String, Object> fetchCelebrities() throws IOException {
    GetAllCelebrities getAllCelebrities = new GetAllCelebrities("en");
    getAllCelebrities.connect();
    return getAllCelebrities.getResponseData();
}

private boolean performLogin() throws IOException {
    String loginIDString = loginID.getText();
    String loginPasswordString = loginPassword.getText();
    Login login = new Login(loginIDString, loginPasswordString);
    boolean loginResult = login.connect();
    return loginResult;
}
```

Comment: Hi can you also provide your mobile Codenameone ConnectionRequest code?

Comment: I have edited my question and added my client side source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to read all of this code but I'll venture a guess based on the server message. You've set the method to "PUT" along the way in the post put class and that isn't supported by the server yet.

The best way to debug these things is with the network monitor in the Simulator. Its shows the traffic and would have made these things mostly clear

Comment: And the server is actually called. I did a debug and it execute to the last println statement.

Comment: I've specifically set "connectionRequest.setHttpMethod("POST");" and connectionRequest.setPost(true); so it cannot be a PUT connection. (The PostPutConnection is a common class for both Post and Put connection, but in this case it is specifically called as a Post connection.) AND... the server println shows the method is INDEED CALLED, right up to the last println statement. So, if the method is indeed invoked and it responds with 200, what caused Codename to treat it as a 405?

Comment: You asked me to debug in the Simulator. But it works perfectly fine in the Simulator. So, what is the approach to resolve this issue?

Comment: As the server-side is indeed called (I have tested this many times) and evidenced by the printout of "This is printed out!!!" (see above), I think client is expecting a certain MIME Type. What is the response mimetype that Codename One is expecting? (Again, the problem exists only on a real Android device, but the simulator works perfectly.)

Comment: OK. Problem is RESOLVED. There wasn't any problem with the POST connection. After the POST connection is called, it calls a GET connection and that was where the problem lies. I MUST call "connectionRequest.setPost(false)" in addition to "connectionRequest.setHttpMethod("GET")". That solved the whole problem.

Comment: When a post gets redirected the HTTP RFC says the new request should be a post but browsers convert it to a GET. We follow that behavior which is problematic sometimes. That's why you can override `shouldConvertPostToGetOnRedirect()` in the `ConnectionRequest`

Comment: I'm taking note of that. Thanks!